# The probability that two consecutively chosen students are the same sex is $1/2$. What can you say about the number of students in the class?

Tags: probability

Full: A math professor wants to choose two students at random from her class and realizes that the probability that the two students are the same sex is exactly $1/2$. What can you say about the number of students in the class?

I have no idea how to approach this question. I don't understand how the probability of two consecutive/dependent events could end up at $1/2$.

Comment: The probably of them being the same sex is 1/2. If it said the probability of both being male/female, then it would be 1/4.

Comment: Just try various configurations to see what happens.  If, say, you start with $B,B,G,G$ then we compute $P(B,B)=P(G,G)=\frac 12\times \frac 13=\frac 16$ so the probability of a match is $2\times \frac 16=\frac 13\neq \frac 12$ so that combination does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If we ignore the possibility that a student is intersex, then the number of students in the class is $m + f$, where $m$ is the number of male students and $f$ is the number of female students.

The probability that two randomly chosen students are the same sex is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{m}{2} + \dbinom{f}{2}}{\dbinom{m + f}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

If the probability that two randomly chosen students are the same sex is $1/2$, then the probability that two randomly chosen students are of opposite sexes is also $1/2$.   The probability that two randomly chosen students are of opposite sexes is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{m}{1}\dbinom{f}{1}}{\dbinom{m + f}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

If you simplify either expression, you should be able to show that the number of students in the class is a multiple of a particular integer or is one more than a multiple of that integer.  This is easier to do with the second equation.